# Extending local inverses

Tags: real-analysis

So we came across the **inverse function theorem** in our calculus class.

The theorem states that near points where $Df(x) \neq 0$ we may find a local inverse of the map. The "locality" statement of the theorem is tight in a sense that even if $f$ is everywhere locally invertible (i.e. $Df(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ say) then the map does not need to be globally invertible (e.g $f: \mathbb{R}_{>0} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2,\, (r,\alpha) \mapsto (r \cos(\alpha), r \sin(\alpha))$).

Now I got this idea and I was wondering whether it is true and under what name or theory it is covered:
Couldn't we just fix a point $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and look at the local inverse $g_p:U_p \to \mathbb{R}^n$ say. Now the idea would be to extend $g_p$ to the whole of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by taking $q \in U_p$ and look at $g_q$ where both maps must agree on $U_p \cap U_q$. The problem would be (I guess) that when extending in this fashion along some closed path represented by $(p_1,\ldots,p_k,p_1)$ we could run into problems in the overlapping regions at the end when trying to close the path, so $g_{p_1} \neq g'_{p_1}$ in a sense (I hope you get my notation).

In the special case of the map I gave above this is because of the periodicity. So I thought, if we would look at $g_p$ not mapping to $\mathbb{R}^2$ but some sort of surface $\mathbb{R}^2 \times Time$ where $Time$ depends on the path or $(p_1,\ldots,p_n,p_1)$ then maybe we would get a global inverse but not to $\mathbb{R}^2$ but another better suited space.

My Question is: How would this space look like? And if this is always possible, then how to prove it and how to choose the path and time-dependency? As clearly my construction would not cover all points and may depend on the path I choose etc. Or is this idea just suited to the case of periodic functions?

(After some research this seems similar to **Riemannian surfaces** and **monodromy theory**, although I do not know enoughabout them so maybe it is not my place to point out a similiarity.)

Answer (score 1):

[**Covering spaces**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space) were invented to study questions like this.

Your map is of the form $f:X\rightarrow Y$, where $X=(0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}$ and $Y=\mathbb{R}^2\backslash 0$, where $0$ was removed to make $f$ surjective. Slightly more general, $X$ and $Y$ might be open subsets of  $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $f$ a surjective map with invertible derivative at every point.

One then says that $f$ is a *covering map*, if it satisfies an additional condition
([every point in $Y$ has an 'evenly covered' neighbourhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space)), which in the present situation amounts to proving that $f$ has no asymptotic values (see Alexandre Eremenko's answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109364/when-is-a-locally-homeo-a-covering-map)). For your concrete example this is satisfied.

Now if $X$ is connected and $f$ has a right-inverse (also called global section), then it must automatically be diffeomorphism. In your example this cannot be true, because $X$ is simply connected, while $Y$ is not.